# Is there a way to access call log data and SMS log data on an iOS device via an objective-c app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am building an an app that shows aggregated data about calls , similar to this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.movinapp.calls&hl=en .

I am wondering if my app can access call / sms logs e.g. what calls the user made to what numbers.

Assuming the users grants permission to my APP, I am interested in knowing if (any) API is available and can be accessed via objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, (or maybe fortunately given what some apps do with user data) that information is not accessible via the iOS public API.

Comment: Hi, I am also trying smt like this. I know its not possible via public API, but lets say I want to build an app for my company and I need acces to the call log. I found a way to acces it when the device is jailbroken(through private API), but is there a possibility to get to the data when the device is not jailbroken?